# Cloud Run integration tests within Cloud Build steps?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I am looking at what Cloud Run suggests for local testing [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local), which is to `docker run` your
container, and then run your tests against it on localhost:8080. Something like this:

```
PORT=8080 && \
docker run -d -p 8080:${PORT} -e PORT=${PORT} gcr.io/myproject/myimage && \
./runtests.sh
```

Now let's say I want to run these tests as part of a Cloud Build. Is it possible/advisable  to run `docker run` as a Cloud Build step?  I don't see any gcr.io image for docker itself, so I'm guessing not?

Or does it need to be actually deployed to Cloud Run first, then tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should be able to do so. You can create custom steps and there is one image for docker: `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`. There's more information about creating custom steps in the `cloudbuild.yaml` in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config).

Something similar to this should work for you:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'run', '-d', '-p', '8080:8080', '-e', 'PORT=8080', 'gcr.io/myproject/myimage' , './runtests.sh']
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. I was looking in the wrong place for cloud-builders images.